# Django Rest - Serialize relation with inherited models

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have the following model structure:

```
class BaseAccount(models.Model):
    # some code

class AccountTypeA(BaseAccount):
    # some code

class AccountTypeB(BaseAccount):
    # some code
```

Here are my serializers:

```
class BaseAccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   class Meta:
      model = BaseAccount
      fields = '__all__'
```

The extended models are defined exactly in the same way.

When I try to serialize the AccountTypeA, I receive back an error stating that the fields from Base account are unknown.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution to all my problems:
https://pypi.org/project/django-rest-polymorphic/